# How do I completely nuke my system and start afresh?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

On a brand new DoS only laptop I installed Ubuntu. I got `Unable to create disk partitions` so I used a Windows7 installation CD to create disk partitions. I ended up erasing the disk with the Ubuntu and now on booting it goes straight to grub rescue where all disk partitions are unknown filesystem. Neither can I seem to install Windows.

*Any chance of completely nuking my system and starting afresh?*

Comment: You need to install *some* OS on the drive...

Comment: That's another issue. Windows cannot be installed on any of my disks.

Comment: Well, we don't support windows here and you haven't given any information at all to indicate what the actual problem you are having is, so...

Comment: Here's the problem as detailed:

Comment: Installed ubuntu on a dos only system. But wanted to create partitions on 500gb disk. Couldn't unmount it on gparted. So used an old Windows 7 installer cd to create partitions. Here I ended up erasing the data on the unmountable partition. But couldn't install Windows either as  my disks are mbr not gpt. When I boot now, it goes straight to grub rescue where none of the listed partitions are recognised.

Comment: @VivekGopinathan: If the below answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

**Before you proceed:** *If you have an UEFI system, this will nuke UEFI too*, but [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is a good replacement...

Are you sure?  *Really sure???* - Well, then just:

1. Boot the Ubuntu Installation media.
2. Choose <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd>.
3. Start `gparted` from the dash.
4. Go to the correct hdd on the top right corner:

   [image: gparted screen]
5. Click: <kbd>Device</kbd>.
6. Click: <kbd>Partition table</kbd>.
7. If you don't care about Windows, choose `gpt`, otherwise choose `msdos` in the screen below:

   [image]
8. Click: <kbd>Apply</kbd> on the screen above.
9. Click the Install Ubuntu icon and [follow these instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

Comment: UEFI is the new version of BIOS. How can formatting a hard drive wipe that? Does that mean you can't replace the hard drive on a UEFI system?

Comment: @SuperSluether: you definitely need to read up on [UEFI here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html)...  And after reading that: give me an upvote!  **:P**

Comment: Ah. In that case, I'm glad I don't have a UEFI motherboard. Sounds like a mess when you want to install your own OS.

Comment: @SuperSluether Not if you use rEFInd afterwards...  **;-)**  Good night!